# mutual distance between each 2 points in 3D

Tags: matlab

```
rv=[rx ry rz];   %# [N-by-3] rx , ry , rz are [N-by-1]

for i=1:N
    for j=1:N
        dx(i,j)=rv(i,1)-rv(j,1);    %# dx is x component of distance between each 2 points [N-by-N]
        dy(i,j)=rv(i,2)-rv(j,2);
        dz(i,j)=rv(i,3)-rv(j,3);
    end
end
d=cat(3,dx,dy,dz);
```

Is there a faster method to construct **d** ?

Thanks a lot for any guide.

Edit:

```
N= 997 
Me:               Elapsed time is 17.271125 seconds.
DiggyF:           Elapsed time is 0.241841 seconds.
Oli Charlesworth: Elapsed time is 0.120425 seconds.
N=1986 
DiggyF          : Elapsed time is 1.183639 seconds.
Oli Charlesworth: Elapsed time is 0.502964 seconds.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a method that avoids the explicit loops:

```
dx = repmat(rx, 1, N) - repmat(rx.', N, 1);
```

I don't know whether that would work faster; you'd have to try it!

Answer (score 1):

This would also work:

```
dx = meshgrid(rx) - meshgrid(rx)'
dy = meshgrid(ry) - meshgrid(ry)'
dz = meshgrid(rz) - meshgrid(ry)'
```

Also look at the [pdist](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/pdist.html) function if you have the statistics toolbox or octave.